# How to add EventHandler OnCommand for ImageButton programaticly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code, where i add ImageButton to table programaticly and I need to assign event handler to this ImageButton. When I write ASP/HTML code, there is attribute OnCommand, but in C#, there is nothing like this. Just CommandName and CommandAttribute.

```
ImageButton ib = new ImageButton
                     {
                         CommandName = "Edit",
                         CommandArgument = id.ToString(),
                         ImageUrl = "~/Images/icons/paper_pencil_48.png",
                         AlternateText = "Edit document"
                     };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In ASP.NET the attribute is named "On" + name of event.**

**In C# it's the name of the event only: [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.command.aspx).**

So let's say you're adding the image button on page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = 0;
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton
    {
        CommandName = "Edit",
        CommandArgument = id.ToString(),
        ImageUrl = "~/Images/icons/paper_pencil_48.png",
        AlternateText = "Edit document"
    };
    ib.Command += ImageButton_OnCommand;

    form1.Controls.Add(ib);
}
```

This is your answer, just like dtb says:

```
ib.Command += ImageButton_OnCommand;
```

And then you have the event handler itself, just to be complete:

```
void ImageButton_OnCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle image button command event
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers cannot be added with object initializer syntax. You need to add them separately:

```
ImageButton ib = new ImageButton { ... };
ib.Command += ImageButton_Command;
```

Answer (score 0):

ib.Command +=

Buddy add this code after that line, and click tab two consegetive times, your work is done.